# \fxnote won't be suggested as a command in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I have a problem wit the `fixme` package, I can get it to work, but it wont be suggested as a command. I know that it works because when I write `\fxnote{something}` it compiles without a problem. I have made sure that I got it as an `.cwl` file in the correct folder and in the TeXstudio editor (the on I use) I have forced it to be recognized as an command. I have uploaded some screenshots that shows what I have written above:

[image]

Can anyone help without suggesting that I change editor? I really like TeXstudio?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, the fixme.cwl was autogenerated. It seems that in this case the autogeneration mechanism was not able to extract the information from the fixme package that `\fxnote` is a valid command. Check if `\fxnote` is in your fixme.cwl. If not, simply add it (Note: You need to restart TXS afterwards).

If this did not help, see the FAQ on [unrecognized commands](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_does_TeXstudio_mark_a_command_as_unrecognized.3F) and [commands not showing in the completer](https://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/texstudio/index.php?title=Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_does_a_command_not_show_up_in_the_completion.3F).